# How do I Insert an element to my Array

Tags: java, arrays, search, for-loop, insert

```
public class My_Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(); 
        int[] array = new int[100];

        array[0] = 1;
        array[1] = 2;
        array[2] = 3;
        array[3] = 4;
        items_arr = 4;

        System.out.println("The elements in the array are: ");
        for (x=0;x<items_arr;x++)
            System.out.println("\t-Array["+x+"]="+array[x]);

        System.out.print("Search for the element:");
        search = input.nextInt();
        for(s = 0; s < items_arr; s++)
            if(array[s] == search)
                break;

        if(s == items_arr){
            System.out.print("\t---Can't find "+ search);
        }else{
            System.out.println("\t---Found " +search);

            System.out.print("Insert an Element: ");
            insert = input.nextInt();   

            for(int k = j; k < items_arr; k++)
                array[k] = array[k+1];

            if(array[j] == insert);

            items_arr++;

            for(int j = 0; j<items_arr-1; j++)
                System.out.println("Array["+j+"]="+array[j]);
        }
    }
```

My problem is in this code I can search elements in my arrays.. Now what I don't know is how do I insert an element to my existing array.. any clues?

Comment: `array[index] = someInteger`.

Comment: What do you mean by insert? Lets say have array `{3,4,5}` and you want to insert element `1` at position `[0]` do you expect `{0,3,4,5}` or `{0,4,5}`?

Comment: no... insert like when the system asks me "Insert an Element" if i choose 1 it will add like this 
    -Array[0]=1
    -Array[1]=2
    -Array[2]=3
    -Array[3]=4
    -Array[4]=5 this becomes a new element

Comment: Your example is not clear. Do you mean that you want to add the new element to the head of your array?

Comment: What is the rule of adding new element? Does it involve resizing array? If so then better structure would be `List` like `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Joey I tried to fix the indentation of your code, but at least the line `if(array[j] == insert);` probably does not do what you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
        array[0] = 1;
        array[1] = 2;
        array[2] = 3;
        array[3] = 4;
```

Here you are already doing something like insert. Since there is no method to add element to `Array`. We can do assign value to position(`index`).

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new inputStreamReader(System.in));
array[index]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Comment: Why do you suddenly forsaken the `Scanner`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to move all the elements one place to the right and then place the new element at the empty position:

```
insertIndex = input.nextInt();
insertElemen = input.nextInt();

if (0 <= insertIndex && insertIndex <= items_arr)
{

    for (int i = items_arr; i > insertIndex; --i)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
    }

    arr[insertIndex] = insertElement;
    ++items_arr;
}
```

Comment: Well, if you have the array [2 4 1 6] and you want to put 10 in position 2, i.e. between the 4 and the 1, then: 1. the for loop make the following - [2 4 1 6 6], [2 4 1 1 6]; 2. then, you place the new element at position 2, i.e. you receive [2 4 10 1 6], and you have inserted element 10 at position 2. NB! Take in mind that if you have multiple inserts, you will get out of bounds soon. One possible solution is to use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of an array.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to add an element to your array adding a new position you just have to array.push('value');

And if you want it in an exact position of your array then. array[pos]='value';

Comment: An array is not a stack. Arrays don't have a `push()` method.